# Get Price from Table in excel using lookup or macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have table "PriceList" in excel with below structure

```
Type       Thickness     width    Height     Price
iron          5            7        10         20
iron          10           10       15         24
iron          12           14       17         26
```

how can i find the price if some-one enters type iron, thickness 10, width 9, height 14 using vlookup or macro. i have tried using vlookup but its not works and later on i found on google that Vlookup only retrieve data with one parameter. Can i do this using macro like we do for selecting sheet data using queries

```
select * from [sheet1$] where col1=x
```

Please suggest??

Edit: i have calculated the above using [this](http://chandoo.org/wp/2012/04/02/using-excel-as-your-database/). Now i am calling this macro on sheet change event like below

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

If Target.Column = 41 Or Target.Column = 43 Or Target.Column = 45 Or Target.Column = 46 Then
Dim i As Currency
i = Calculate_CorePrice(cell(Target.Row, 46).Value, cell(Target.Row, 45).Value, cell(Target.Row, 41).Value, cell(Target.Row, 43).Value, "RWJ Doorset Schedule", "ED15")
cell(Target.Row, 134).Value = i
End If

End Sub
```

if i debug the function itself with hard-coded values, it is working but if i call the function as in above way, it does not return value and i am not able to debug sheet_change event.

How can i debug this event.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming your columns are A, B, C, etc. You can use an Index/Match formula as an array (enter with <kbd>CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER</kbd>).

If the user enters the type, thickness, width, and height in `W1`, `X1`, `Y1`, and `Z1`, you can use:

`=Index($E$2:$E$10,Match(W1&X1&Y1&Z1,$A$2:$A$10&$B$2:$B$10&$C$2:$C$10&$D$2:$D$10,0))`

It's convoluted, but basically the `Match` part is you are looking for `W1` in the range `A2:A10`, then whatever is in `X1`, you will search `B2:B10`, etc.

Comment: Nice! Since you're looking for exact values maybe `IFERROR()` might be additionally useful, as well.

Comment: its not to equate but have to use less then concept for the width, height and thickness for getting price. for example thickness 11, width 13 and height 15 price will be 26

Comment: @Vikky - What if thickness is 11, width is 14, height is 9? Does *each* variable need to check for "less than"?

Comment: in the case it will be 26. yes like in sql we did thickness<=@thk

Comment: I like this approach. You should add some formatting like `TEXT($B$2:$B$10,"000")` to your match formula. Otherwise you get problems if you have values like `iron,11,2,3` and `iron, 1,12,3`.

Answer (score 2):

It seems I am just a bit late with my answer and @BruceWayne beat me to it. Still, I will add my solution as well as there is a nice little illustration to it:

[image]

Basically, it is the same proposal has been already proposed. Just use an array formula and the `&` sign to combine all criteria into one. In the end a criteria will look like this `iron101015` (for example). And it will be compared to all the combinations in the table.

Comment: it is not about matching, it is about to find within certain range, for example  thickness 11, width 13 and height 15 price will be 26.

Comment: And what would be the price for thickness 3, width 10, and height 18? What about this formula instead: `{=INDEX(Table1[Price];MATCH(B7*1000000+C7*1000+D7;Table1[Thickness]*1000000+Table1[width]*1000+Table1[Height];1))}`

Answer (score 1):

The best would be to loop through the data, using an if statement to check the data tables. (This could be placed in a sub or in a function depending on how you want the data to be retrieved)

```
Function GetPrice(Type As String, Thickness As Integer, Width As Integer, Height As Integer)

Dim ItemRow As Range, SearchColumn As Range
'Dim Price As Double   'Use variable if this were a sub
Set SearchColumn = Range(Cells(2,1),Cells(ActiveSheet.UsedRange.rows.count,1))
For Each ItemRow In SearchColumn
    If ItemRow.Value = Type AND ItemRow.Offset(0,1).Value >= Thickness AND ItemRow.Offset(0,2).Value >= Width AND ItemRow.Offset(0,3).Value >= Height AND ItemRow.Offset(-1,1).Value < Thickness AND ItemRow.Offset(-1,2).Value < Width AND ItemRow.Offset(-1,3).Value < Height Then
         'Price = ItemRow.Offset(0,4).Value
         GetPrice = ItemRow.Offset(0,4).Value
         Exit For
    End If
Next ItemRow

End Function
```

Edit: Given your comment on another answer, I've adjusted the code to find the value as i believe you are looking for

Comment: @Vikky I think we are having trouble understanding how your data is structured.  I am familiar with SQL so you can explain it in those terms if that is easier for you

Comment: i have created a lookup table in excel, having the same structure in question. i have to find the price based on height, width, thickness and type. Suppose someone is buying a material of  thickness 11, width 13 and height 15, the suited price will be 26. The values mentioned in the table is minimum/ maximum size.